# Pop up ad works, but not once I implement in-app purchase to remove it?

Tags: ios, swift, ads, storekit

The test ad works fine when I don't include the in app purchase. I click on the cell, it takes me to the next view controller, and the ad pops up. However, when I include in-app purchases the ad doesn't show up even if the user didn't pay to remove ads.

The ad shows up with this function:

```
func showAd() {

   self.interstitial = createInterstitialAd()

}
```

But when I add this, the ad doesn't show even if the user hasn't paid to remove ads.

```
func showAd() {

    if let purchased = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "payment") as? Bool{
        if purchased == true{
            interstitial = nil
            print("there is no ad!!!!")
        }else{
            self.interstitial = createInterstitialAd()
            print("there is an ad!!!")
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that initially  there will be no value in `UserDefaults` for the *payment* key.  This will cause the outer `if` statement to fall through, resulting in no ad.

You can make your code simpler by using `bool(forKey:)` - This will return `false` where the key is not present in `UserDefaults` rather than `nil`:

```
func showAd() {

    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "payment") {
        interstitial = nil
        print("there is no ad!!!!")
    } else {
        self.interstitial = createInterstitialAd()
        print("there is an ad!!!")
    }

}
```